# Help solving Sliding Tiles Puzzle 2x3

Tags: sliding-blocks

So, I'm playing a game (The Da Vinci Code) and are really stuck on a 2x3 tile sliding puzzle. It looks something like this

1 - 5 - 4

2 - x - 3

and it has to look like this:

1 - 4 - 5

2 - 3 - x

if anyone has any idea how to solve it I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is impossible.

With the [15 Puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) and its variants, you can only ever reach half of the possible configurations. In particular, if you can reach a configuration, you *cannot* ever reach a single swap away from that configuration (but you can always reach any *two* swaps away, and you cannot reach three...)

Here, you can reach one swap away from your goal by just pushing the 3 left. So you cannot reach the goal itself.

Comment: How is swap defined here? Just a swap between two tiles? I guess there must be a lateral solution to the OPs puzzle. Like turning the puzzle upside-down?

Comment: @DrXorile Yes, just a swap between two tiles. And even that won't work - when there's a hole in the center, turning the puzzle upside down is just two swaps of opposite corners plus a single move, so parity is maintained. (And when the hole is somewhere else, that's just a move, a flip as above, and a move back, all of which maintain parity.)

Comment: Could it be that the video game is poorly made then?

Comment: @BurnedP Yes, that would be my best guess. Either that or there's some sort of trick to it.